# How to prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{14a^2+b^2+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{14b^2+a^2+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{14c^2+b^2+a^2}}\ge \frac{9}{4(a+b+c)}$?

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, holder-inequality, buffalo-way

Prove that$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{14a^2+b^2+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{14b^2+a^2+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{14c^2+b^2+a^2}}\ge \frac{9}{4(a+b+c)},$$holds for all $a,b,c>0.$

I tried to use C-S $\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}+\dfrac{1}{z}\ge \frac{9}{x+y+z}$ and we'll prove that $$\sqrt{14a^2+b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{14b^2+a^2+c^2}+\sqrt{14c^2+b^2+a^2}\le 4(a+b+c)$$
The last inequality is totally wrong.

Hope to see some better ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By Holder $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{14a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(14a^2+b^2+c^2)(4a^2+15b^2+15c^2+48bc+10ab+10ac)^3\geq$$
$$\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}(4a^2+15b^2+15c^2+48bc+10ab+10ac)\right)^3=34^3(a+b+c)^6$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$34^3\cdot16(a+b+c)^8\geq81\sum_{cyc}(14a^2+b^2+c^2)(4a^2+15b^2+15c^2+48bc+10ab+10ac)^3,$$ which is obvious by [BW](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=34%5E3%2816%29%28x%2By%2Bz%29%5E8-81%28%2814x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%284x%5E2%2B15y%5E2%2B15z%5E2%2B48yz%2B10xy%2B10xz%29%5E3%2B%2814y%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29%284y%5E2%2B15x%5E2%2B15z%5E2%2B48xz%2B10xy%2B10yz%29%5E3%2B%2814z%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29%284z%5E2%2B15y%5E2%2B15x%5E2%2B48yx%2B10zy%2B10xz%29%5E3%29%2Cx%3Da%2Cy%3Da%2Bu%2Cz%3Da%2Bv).

We can get a factor $(4a^2+15b^2+15c^2+48bc+10ab+10ac)^3$ by the following reasoning.

For non-negatives $k$, $m$ and $n$ by Holder $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{14a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(14a^2+b^2+c^2)(ka^2+b^2+c^2+mbc+nab+nac)^3\geq$$
$$\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}(ka^2+b^2+c^2+mbc+nab+nac)\right)^3.$$

The equality occurs for $$\sqrt{14a^2+b^2+c^2}(ka^2+b^2+c^2+mbc+nab+nac)=$$
$$=\sqrt{14b^2+c^2+a^2}(kb^2+c^2+a^2+mca+nab+nbc)=$$
$$=\sqrt{14c^2+a^2+b^2}(kc^2+a^2+b^2+mab+nbc+nac).$$

We know that there are troubles around points $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$.

Also, we want to get from $ka^2+b^2+c^2+mbc+nab+nac$ a nice expression, for which we'll assume $m+2n=2(k+2)$.

After solving this system we obtain:
$$(k,m,n)\approx\left(\frac{4}{15}\frac{16}{5},\frac{2}{3}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for help. I am confusing how did you use Holder like that. Can you explain it to us?

Comment: It's Bacteria. In evening I'll explain

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is there simpler way by Holder? I try with $(b+c+ka)^3$ without success.

Comment: @TATA box I tried. It does not help.